# How to change spring application name while registering with eureka

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

By default eureka uses spring.application.name for application name. don't want to use the default one. Any property to change application name in eureka ?

Answer (score 3):

Try `eureka.instance.appname` checkout [EurekaInstanceConfigBean](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/main/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaInstanceConfigBean.java#L58).